# Find out the used email account by google developer console project id

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, service-accounts, google-developers-console

To get Google Analytics data from their API we are using a service account with `p12` key, the GA API working fine but sometime I get **Rate Limit** error so I just planned to update my limit from the console but I just forgot which email account I used previously for that developer console project. So now I just want to know is there any way I can find out which **email** account is associated with my Google Analytics Service account's project id?

Currently I am getting this error when exceed the daily call rate of that GA API.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A79X6089300&start-date=2019-01-31&end-date=2019-01-31&metrics=ga%3AuniqueEvents&dimensions=ga%3AeventLabel&filters=ga%3AeventCategory%3D%3DImage+Missing%3Bga%3AeventAction%3D%3D11%3Bga%3AuniqueEvents%3E2&start-index=1&max-results=1000:
>   (403) Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight
>   Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits
>   in the API Console:
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/quotas?project=**XXXXXXXXXXXX**'
>   in /var/www/html/GoogleServerApi/src/Google/Http/REST.php:79 Stack
>   trace: #0 /var/www/html/GoogleServerApi/src/Google/Http/REST.php(44):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #1
>   /var/www/html/GoogleServerApi/src/Google/Client.php(499):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   /var/www/html/GoogleServerApi/src/Google/Service/Resource in
>   /var/www/html/GoogleServerApi/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 79

The error itself say monitor my quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console but I don't remember my associated email id. **So I just need help on that How can it get the associated EMAIL by my project id?** You can also Let me know any forum or group where I can get help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to track a service account back to the Google account used to create it on google developer console.

Comment: I dont think so.   Not sure how you would even go about finding someone to contact.   Just create a new service account and use that.

Comment: actually we've a meeting with Team Google next week, so I'm having some hope for that

Comment: one follow up question is it possible to grt the project name by project id?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny any solution you got?

Comment: @sultanaslam no solution